# Javascript/jquery not working on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a site, tested out on my local server and it worked fine, but once I moved it over ot my host anything to do with javascript/jquery on the page just refuses to work :/

http://www.neuromanga.com/mangaReader1.0.php?cid=1

could someone please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `<script>` tags in your Javascript file. They need to be removed. I think this will fix your problem.

Comment: Indeed, that is the issue. @dbomb101 use your browser's web developer tools; available on modern browsers (IE9b's pretty good), or Firebug on Firefox.

Comment: I removed the tags, but it hasn't solved the problem trying to use fire-bug, but not too familiar with it

Comment: Your AJAX request is returning the following: `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>/homez.380/mangasma/www/pageCall.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
[]`  I suspect your database settings are incorrect for the different server.

Comment: the spelling for one of the tables was slightly different from the one on the test server, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `<Script>` and `</Script>` tags from your Mangacaller.js file.

if you use `<Script src='...'/>` you don't use the script tags in that source file.

Answer (score 1):

The external script (*Mangacaller.js*) should not have the `<script type="text/javascript">` and the corresponding `</script>` inside the external file. The external file should be all JavaScript without any HTML (it's **just** the stuff that would go **between** the `<script>` tags if you embedded the script inside the HTML instead of referencing it as an external script). The browser parses this entire external file as JavaScript, not HTML, so there should be no HTML within the *Mangacaller.js* file.